# Selenium: "element not interactable error" when accessing the CAISO website but only for downloadNetDemandCSV, but not for downloadDemandCSV

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to fix this code to extract data from it. The code is publicly available here: https://github.com/grgmiller/CAISO_operations/blob/master/CAISO_operations.py

This code used to worked in 2020, but currently does not due to slight changes in the website, and its use of now-depreciated methods.

The first thing I did was to downgrade selenium to version 4.0.0 to factor out the errors created by the depreciated methods. Next, I added one line of code to the downloadCurtialment function after

```
curtail_read = pd.read_csv(curtailments / 'curtailment_data.csv', dtype=ct_dtypes) #load the csv into a dataframe
```

:

```
curtail_read = curtail_read.drop(columns=['Reason']) # Reason is not needed
```

The 'Reason' column was not originally in the dataset used in the code, so I dropped it from the dataframe.

The problem I am currently having is with the second to last line of code in the downloadDemand function:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('downloadNetDemandCSV').click() #download CSV file
```

I get this error output:

```
  File "/home/luis/Research/CAISO_operations/CAISO_operations.py", line 101, in main
    downloadDemand(browser, dataDate)
  File "/home/luis/Research/CAISO_operations/CAISO_operations.py", line 253, in downloadDemand
    browser.find_element_by_id('downloadNetDemandCSV').click() #download CSV file
  File "/home/luis/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/luis/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/luis/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/luis/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.58)
```

I am a little bit lost about this error since it can do

```
browser.find_element_by_id('downloadDemandCSV').click() #download CSV file
```

just fine with downloadDemand.csv, and I checked the browser console, and both 'downloadDemandCSV'and 'downloadNetDemandCSV' are there in the dropdown medium. I cannot figure out what can be there error. Here is the website the code references. http://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/default.aspx#section-net-demand-trend

I am using Linux Mint 21.2 and Chromium 123.0.6312.58

Thank you all for the help, and apologize if it is something trivial I am new to selenium and web scraping in general.